# How to track file location?

Tags: mac, unix, symbolic-link

I want to track the paths of specific folders in my system in as simple and efficient of a way as possible. My first assumption was that I could achieve this using symlinks, but I see contradicting information on how a symlink works.

Many questions have asked how to [get the path to a symlink target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47710/find-only-destination-of-symlink) (with answers such as "use `greadlink`"). But I cannot find any question asking how to get the *current* target path, since all the answers I've found seem to only get the *original* target path.

But as I search for a way to find the current target path, all of the answers seem to be saying that this is not possible since after the target has moved, the symlink becomes "broken".  I do not understand why they consider this link broken. If I make symlink B to target A and then mv A to a new location, symlink B still works for me. It still displays the updated content of A, even if changes are made to A after A has been moved. And in Path Finder, selecting 'Show Original' in the context menu for B brings me to the *updated* path of A. And yet, 'greadlink B' only points to the original location of A and not the current.

While I did specifically mention symlinks, my broader and more important question is how to get a file's location after it has been moved. The best solution I've found so far is to use `find` in some way, but this is way too slow when I am trying to track more than a few files. But symlinks in Path Finder seem track target locations effectively, so I know it must be possible.

Comment: A moved symbolic work will be valid only if an absolute path was used to create it; a relative path will normally fail (unless the target begins with one of more instances of `../` and the link is moved to a directory at the same level in the hierarchy).

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing up Unix symlinks and macOS aliases?

Comment: @AFH thanks for the clarification. Do you know how to get the updated path?

Comment: You can use `ls -l` to show the link target. If it's a directory link and you add a trailing `/` you will see the contents of the target directory.

Comment: @grawity Your comment lead me to the solution. I'm writing up an answer and crediting you.

Comment: Now that you’ve found an answer, please update the question to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @grawity for reminding me about aliases. I tried using an alias instead of a symlink to track a files location. It turns out that I can use the following script, which will return the *current* path to the target even after the target has moved.

**ResolveAlias.applescript**

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run argv
    tell application "Finder"
        set theItem to (POSIX file (item 1 of argv)) as alias
        if the kind of theItem is "alias" then
            get the POSIX path of (original item of theItem as text)
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

Invoked with `osascript "/path/to/ResolveAlias.applescript" "/path/to/alias"`

Comment: This solution turns out not to be the best. Through testing I found that Finder does not update the alias target path right away after it has been moved, but only after some arbitrary amount of time. I've seen it update in seconds in some cases and never in other cases (didn't try waiting more than a few min, so I'm assuming it would have updated eventually). On the bright side, the alias target path always correctly resets after relaunching Finder from the Force Quit winodw.